# Google Maps & javascript how to dynamically update (re-display) custom map tiles?

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, overlay, tiles

I have a database with thousands of (latitude,longitude) points stored in it. Those points are plotted into a map using a tile server. Such tile server first computes, for each tile, the points that fall inside the tile, and then draws every point(after coordinates conversion). My Javascript looks as follows:

```
var overlayMaps = [{
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    return "tileserver.php?x="+coord.x+"&y="+coord.y+"&z="+zoom+"&g=1";
  },

  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  isPng: true,
  opacity: 1.0
}];

var overlayMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType(overlayMaps[0]);
map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(0,overlayMap);
```

Now, I am dynamically adding new records to the database every 5 seconds, and I want the respective tiles to be updated (re-computed and re-displayed) every 5 seconds.

How could I trigger my tile server to re-compute tiles of the viewport every 5 seconds ?

*Added: The tiles are updated every 5 seconds without problems, but the main problem now is re-displaying them on the map...*

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the current time instead of a random number  (as the r you stated ), and it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiles are images,you can't possibly know which one of these may change.Also,you can't refresh single tiles but entire viewport.All you can do,serving your tiles dynamically,each time viewport changes or not tile images not cached,so they always change.For this,you can put a time flag or random number into your tile url code like this.

```
"tileserver.php?x="+coord.x+"&y="+coord.y+"&z="+zoom+"&g=1&r=" + Math.random();
```

Best Regards

Comment: Although having such parameter is a good option,  tiles will be blinking for a moment when reloaded. those who want to avoid this please visit the following link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/JaPykM3w-l4/discussion

Comment: Changing opacity until tile becomes invisible,then releasing tile,then reloading it looks better idea.I will try this method as well.Thank you for sharing David